# Transit Directions: Preferred Vehicle Type?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, transit

I would like to be able to get transit directions through the JS api, that is limited to a single vehicle type (e.g. Bus). This functionality is available on maps.google.com, but how do i submit the vehicle type as part of the DirectionsRequest?. 
Using the code below will provide routes via Bus, Train

```
google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
```

But if i want to restrict only to Train, how do i do it?

Comment: but it is not working with this code help me out ..plzzzz it's urgent
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <head> <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Displaying text directions with <code>setPanel()</code></title> <style> html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px } #panel { position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 50%; margin-left: -180px; z-index: 5; background-color: #fff; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #999; } </style> <style> #directions-panel { height: 100%; float: right; width: 390px; overflow: auto; } #map-canvas { mar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**google.maps.VehicleType** object specification

Possible values for vehicle types. These values are specifed as strings, i.e. 'BUS' or 'TRAIN'.

> BUS       Bus.
>
> CABLE_CAR     A vehicle that operates on a cable, usually on the ground.
>   Aerial cable cars may be of the type GONDOLA_LIFT.
>
> COMMUTER_TRAIN    Commuter rail.
>
> FERRY     Ferry.
>
> FUNICULAR     A vehicle that is pulled up a steep incline by a cable.
>
> GONDOLA_LIFT  An aerial cable car.
>
> HEAVY_RAIL    Heavy rail.
>
> HIGH_SPEED_TRAIN  High speed train.
>
> INTERCITY_BUS Intercity bus.
>
> METRO_RAIL Light rail.
>
> MONORAIL Monorail.
>
> OTHER         Other vehicles. RAIL    Rail.
>
> SHARE_TAXI Share taxi is a sort of bus transport with ability to drop
>   off and pick up passengers anywhere on its route. Generally share taxi
>   uses minibus vehicles. SUBWAY     Underground light rail.
>
> TRAM  Above ground light rail.
>
> TROLLEYBUS    Trolleybus.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#VehicleType

Comment: Configuring "google.maps.VehicleType" might be a google support issue see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842296/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-specify-vehicletype